# When deploying ckeditor do I need to include the plugins folder?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using ckEditor to provide WYSIWYG editing for my users

When deploying ckeditor do I need to include the plugins folder?
Or are all of the plugins that are required for basic use packaged into ckeditor.js?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the folders one by one.

Some are optional plugins not included in the core and other folders include the dialogs, that aren't included in the core unless you create a new build including the things that you want.

Comment: I am only including ckedit.js in my html. Is there any way that those optional plugins would be loaded? or are there any images, or css that would be used by the core?

Comment: yes of course: if you try to insert an image it will load the image dialog. Just by loading the editor you will load the main css and the toolbar images. If you look at the network request with firebug or any other developer tool you will see all the stuff that it's loaded and when.